# Is it possible to trigger a spark job from the flink job and get the data from it?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-flink, azure-data-lake

I am using flink to read the data from Azure data lake. But flink is not able to find the Azure data lake file system. I have implemented spark to read the Azure Data Lake file system files.

So what I am trying is to trigger the spark from flink to read the data from the Azure Data lake and do some logic and return the list to flink. So the flink could use that data?

Is it possible to trigger the spark job from flink? Or how to configure flink to understand the Azure Data lake file system. Could anyone guide me in this?

Comment: Hi Dhinesh, is it not possible to use this same mechanism that enables you to read from ADLS from Spark via Flink? https://medium.com/azure-data-lake/connecting-your-own-hadoop-or-spark-to-azure-data-lake-store-93d426d6a5f4

Comment: @Amit Kulkarni. Thanks for the guidance, now I have configured flink to understand the Azure datalake file system.

Comment: Awesome. Please mark the below as the answer in that case.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to get this scenario to work is to read data from ADLS directly. It's convoluted to do it by triggering another mechanism such as Spark.

This SO question contains the information to do so: [how to configure flink to understand the Azure Data Lake file system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45029639/how-to-configure-flink-to-understand-the-azure-data-lake-file-system/45042596)